# zero knowledge framework for c programs - how to prove correct C program execution with private inputs

Tags: implementation, zero-knowledge-proofs

I am looking for a zk framework that could be used for proving correct execution of programs written in C (or any other high level language) such as:

 I know x s.t. SHA-256(x) = y (y is public, x is prover's private input)

or in pseude code:

```
void compute(_ *prover_input, _ *verifier_input, _ *output){
    *output = sha256(*prover_input) == *verifier_input;
 }
```

So far I found pepper project which seems pretty close but it lacks the prover's private input part/zero knowledge part.

I also want to compute more functions than sha and combine them in one proof.

Comment: Are you talking about general computation (i.e., any arbitrary program)?

Comment: @cygnusv yes, I want general computation, like computing hash functions, encryptions, signatures

Comment: Well, Pinocchio can compile C (or at least a sufficiently large subset of it for your purposes) to arithmetic circuits, so what you want is doable in it but may be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

[pepper project](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin) does not lack private input functionality. It does support that with `exo_compute` method. Probably it didn't when you asked the question, but now it does.

Check [here](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin/blob/master/exo_compute.txt) for more details about `exo_compute`. Also, I have implemented in a pull-request the scenario you mentioned where a prover knows the pre-image of a hash function and he/she does not disclose it to the verifier. See [here](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin/blob/master/pepper/apps/prover_knows_hash_preimage.c) for the source code and [here](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin/pull/27) for more details about the PR.